# How to add a value to every element inside a list?

Tags: python, list

```py
value = int(input("Enter the value"))
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If the input value is 5, I want to add 5 to every element in my_list where the expect outcome should be `[6,7,8,9,10]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways:

```py
value = int(input("Enter the value"))
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Using map()
new_list = list(map(lambda list_value: list_value + value, my_list))

# Using list comprehension
new_list = [list_value + value for list_value in my_list]
```

Or, if you are using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

value = int(input("Enter the value"))

my_list = np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) + value
```

Answer (score 2):

That's very simple:

```
value = int(input("Enter the value"))
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_list = [x+value for x in my_list]
```

This basically creates a new list by iterating over the elements of the old one and adding `value` to them.

This method is called "list comprehension". It allows you to create new lists in a concise way. Common applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of some operations applied to each member of another list, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a certain condition. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple `for` loop:

```
for i, e in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[i] = value + e
print(my_list)
```

output(for input 5):

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

or you can use the built-in functions: `map`, `sum` and `zip`:

```
list(map(sum, zip(my_list, [value]*len(my_list))))
```

or you can use `itertools.cycle`

```
from itertools import cycle

list(map(sum, zip(my_list, cycle([value]))))
```